# Unusual error when trying to hide Google Maps API keys in either .env file or local.properties file in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps, api-key

while running the app build using flutter after implementing measures taken to hide API keys in project, such as:

1. passing key as variable declared in .env file in root folder, to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; or
2. variable declared in local.properties file, calling in AndroidManifest.xml,

despite implementing both solutions separately yields the following error:

```
Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.geo.API_KEY@value at AndroidManifest.xml:31:9-40 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <maps_api_key> is provided.
C:\Users\h\Desktop\Projects\SportMap\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

[error description in debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVj1R.png)
further context:

- [variable declaration in local.properties(declared similarly in .env also)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UEXd.png)
- [How its called in AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43xbf.png)

**is there any other way of passing API key such that it is not visible in version control?**

Tried running `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` to delete and reload  project build. However this resulted in a new set of errors.
Did this repeatedly till that error got resolved.

Still left with original issue though.

Answer (score 0):

just leave the keys in, its fine. Maps keys are not that likely to be abused.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).